# How to call same name dynamic function from dynamically created files based database inputs

Tags: php

I'm creating a system that would work on call same function names from dynamic created php files.

The file structure is as bellow :

- /root/caller.php  //{uses pthreads & process multi simultaniously}
- /root/rules/mode1.php
- /root/rules/mode2.php
- /root/rules/mode{n}.php // goes till n , so unlimited

Caller.php reads data from db and calls mode{n} accordingly. Sometimes there are chances to call multiple of rules at a point of time.

Sample of caller.php {written on OOPS}

```
foreach ($result as $row){
     $mode = $rom->modeNum;
     include 'rules/mode' . $mode . '.php';
     call_fuction_inside_mode();    
}
```

Sample of mode{n}.php {procedural programming}

```
function call_fuction_inside_mode(){
    //..Custom function depending upon mode{n}
}
```

This won't function properly, because caller.php would include same function name again and again.

Please note :

- I do not want to play with rename function with pecl, as all includes would be required
- I have tried calling mode{n}.php by introducing another file "proxy.php"

And proxy.php works in below pattern

caller.php -> curl 127.0.0.1/proxy.php?mode={n} -> calls as defined

But this is not efficient way to do this when dealing with >500 requests per sec on micro server. I noticed many requests are killed and there's problem with order number. My target is to achieve this with least memory usage and 100% utilization of provided cpu resources.

I'm confused and so curious to find the solution I should be dealing here.

Comment: If you want to keep using functions then make them closures and add them to an array using the number as the index. i.e.`$modeRule[$ruleNo]  = function () { ...};` Then just call them as required: i.e. `$modeRule[$ruleNo]();`

Comment: @RyanVincent  the Mode{n}.php files are written in procedural way. Plus I wanna have same functions named across all files without using specific arrays and classes for easiness, have any clues :)

Comment: The issue is the same function name. There are only a few choices 1) don't declare it more than once 2) Declare them in _different namespaces_. I cannot think of other ways of dealing with it. The different namespaces is your only real choice currently. It wouldn't be difficult to setup. Just a minor change to wrap  your include, in a namespace, in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @RyanVincent I do think namespace is solution to this. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an interface called `Mode` in Mode.php:

```
interface Mode{
    public static function AcivateMode();
}
```

and include Mode.php into your code, then change the code in your `mode{n}.php` to encapsulate your function into classes that implements the `interface` Mode like so:

```
class Mode1 implements Mode {
    public static function AcivateMode() {
        //..Custom function depending upon mode{n}
    }
}
```

then modify your `foreach` to activate the modes like:

```
foreach ($result as $row){
     $mode = $rom->modeNum;
     include 'rules/mode' . $mode . '.php';
     call_user_func("Mode$mode::AcivateMode");
}
```

**OR**

you can use the namespaces approach by adding the namespace to each of your `mode{n}.php` files like so:

**mode1.php**

```
namespace Mode1;
function call_fuction_inside_mode(){....}
```

and calling the function using:

```
call_user_func("Mode$mode\call_fuction_inside_mode");
```

that worked for me, hope it's gonna be helpful :)

Regards,

Comment: Looks good, I wanna know how does that make difference using interface.

Comment: well in your case it won't make a direct noticeable difference, but it would make your code more structured and readable.

Comment: i mean when you isolate the function into classes that will work for your purpose even if you didn't use interfaces, but to make your code more structured using interfaces would be a great idea.

Comment: I thought to use in same way as you mentioned without using interface. But the situation is that, Mode{n}.php files are automatic generated based on several parameters. Plus it would be easy for my team mates to do it in procedural way. Have any clues to do it in procedural way :)

Comment: i think you can use the same approach by changing the name of the function inside the mode{n}.php (i mean while generating them) as follows `mode{n}.php` => `function call_fuction_inside_mode_{n}(){....` and then calling the functions using `call_user_func("call_fuction_inside_mode_{n}"); `

Comment: as I said I wanna have same function names across all mode file. This is used by multiple php, so I'm in situation where I can't change the name of function

Comment: still you can add a namespace to your mode{n}.php like `namespace mode{n};` and call it in your loop as `mode{n}\call_fuction_inside_mode();`.

Comment: namespace sounds good to use. Can you please mention the usage in your answer :)

Comment: Mode1\call_fuction_inside_mode(); how can I call it dynamically Mode{n}\call_fuction_inside_mode();
Is that by using call_fuction_inside_mode. This is last thing that I need to know and then I can use it :)

Comment: use `call_user_func("Mode$mode\call_fuction_inside_mode");`

Comment: superb that should work. Thanks a lot for your valuable time